# ¿Vue.js siempre carga todos los templates en el lado del cliente?

Tags: javascript, web, vue.js

Recientemente, estoy incursionando en el mundo del `vue.js` y a pesar de que entiendo bien todo lo de componentes y esas cosas, hay algo que no acabo de entender.
Al manejar todo el `frontend` dese el lado del cliente, ¿significa esto que se cargan todos los `templates`? y si es así, al tener una aplicación muy grande, no se aumenta mucho el tiempo de carga o se vuelve engorroso el trabajo para el cliente?
Según leí, es posible mandar los `templates` a través de llamados al `backend`, pero esto es lo "no usual". Se me genera esa duda, de si hay algún tamaño donde ya se diga "Tiene un tamaño demasiado grande" o algo así.

Comment: Sí que se puede. Se llama Server Side Rendering y con Vuejs puedes usar Nuxt: https://nuxtjs.org

Comment: Bueno para ayudar en eso **vue js** tiene un DOM virtual que no afecta al rendimiento del usuario y que no carga esos nodos hasta que sean usados

Comment: @LuisDanielRoviraContreras Pero igual el cliente debe descargar todos los templates a su navegador, no? o sea, no se pintan las cosas en pantalla, pero igual tenes que descargar todos los templates, no?

Answer (score 0):

Sí, debe descargar todos los "templates" siempre y cuando estemos hablando de una SPA (Single Page Application), dado que si tienes varios archivos HTMLs puedes tener varios archivos JavaScript con diferentes aplicaciones Vue.

No hay un tiempo específico estipulado sobre cuando moverse hacia el SSR, y ahora explicaré por qué. El SSR (Server-side rendering) es útil cuando el acceso al contenido es parte del *conversion rate*. Este término puede significar muchas cosas dependiendo del negocio al que estemos apuntando, pero básicamente quiere decir que si el tiempo en que se tarda en acceder al contenido es una parte intrínsecamente necesaria para lograr el *engagement* y sin SSR no se está logrando, entonces hay que implementarlo.

Toda la lógica del VueJS, cuando la renderización y por ende el mantenimiento del DOM virtual, están del lado del cliente, va a tener una mayor demora que si utilizaramos SSR (dado que en esta metodología, el HTML "renderizado" viaja como una cadena de texto al cliente).

Yo diría que si no es estrictamente necesario para la conversión, no lo tomes en cuenta aún.

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, pero debes realizar respuestas basadas en [answer].